# How can a make file warning when trying to install Sketchmap on Mac Yosemite?

Tags: macos, gcc, installation, makefile, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to install a piece of software (GISMO - Sketchmap for VMD) on my Mac, Yosemite version 10.10.1. Unfortunately I am getting the same error time again. I understand that it is very likely it can't find something. The directory

```
Anthonys-MacBook-Pro:bin acnash$ pwd
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

does exist, and the make executable is present. Unfortunately I have limited experience with adjusting Make files.

```
>sudo make
Password:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -C libs all
make: *** [libs] Error 2
```

The contents of make.in file:

```
# COMPILER AND COMPILER FLAGS
CXX=gcc
CXXFLAGS:=$(CXXFLAGS) -O3 -ftracer -floop-optimize -funroll-loops

# AUTOMATIC DEPENDENCY GENERATION
MAKEDEPEND=gcc -M $(CXXFLAGS)

# INCLUDES AND LINKER FLAGS
# Lapack includes and linking

ILAPACK=
LLAPACK=-llapack

TBSRC=../libs/
LDFLAGS=-L$(TBSRC) -ltoolbox $(LLAPACK)
CXXFLAGS:=$(CXXFLAGS) -I$(TBSRC) $(ILAPACK)
```

and the contents of Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all clean libs tools distclean

all: libs tools

tools: libs
        $(MAKE) -C tools all

libs:
        $(MAKE) -C libs all

clean:
        $(MAKE) -C libs clean
        $(MAKE) -C tools clean

distclean: clean
        rm -f bin/* libs/libtoolbox.a
```

This is the contents of the libs/Makefile

```
-include ../make.in
.PHONY: all clean
SOURCES=$(shell ls *.cpp)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
DEPENDS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.d)

all: libtoolbox.a

libtoolbox.a: $(OBJECTS)
        ar rcs libtoolbox.a $(OBJECTS)

-include $(DEPENDS)
%.d: %.cpp
        $(MAKEDEPEND) $< > $@.$$$$;                      \
           sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@;     \
           rm -f $@.$$$$

clean:
        rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(DEPENDS)
```

After running make --debug=v from the source root i.e., /Users/acnash/sketchmap-0.2

```
Anthonys-MBP:libs acnash$ make --debug=v
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile `Makefile'...
Reading makefile `../make.in' (search path) (don't care) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `libclparser.d' (search path) (don't care) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `libfmblas.d' (search path) (don't care) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `libinterpol.d' (search path) (don't care) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `libioparser.d' (search path) (don't care) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `liblinalg.d' (search path) (don't care) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `libminsearch.d' (search path) (don't care) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `librndgen.d' (search path) (don't care) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `libtb.d' (search path) (don't care) (no ~ expansion)...
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file `all'.
 File `all' does not exist.
  Considering target file `libtoolbox.a'.
    Considering target file `libclparser.o'.
      Pruning file `libclparser.cpp'.
      Pruning file `libclparser.cpp'.
      Pruning file `clparser.hpp'.
      Pruning file `tbdefs.hpp'.
      Pruning file `/usr/include/c++/4.6/valarray'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file `libclparser.o'.
    Giving up on target file `libclparser.o'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `libtoolbox.a'.
  Giving up on target file `libtoolbox.a'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `all'.
Giving up on target file `all'.
```

Comment: What's in the `libs/Makefile` file? What does running make with `--debug=v` tell you?

Comment: Wait are you running `make` in the source root? Because the Makefile seems to require you do.

Comment: Hi, I've added the contents of libs/Makefile in the edit above and what happens on `debug`

Comment: You appear to have ran make from the `libs` directory, run it in the source root (with the debug flag). Make sure you delete all of the `.o`, `.a`, and `.d` files beforehand, along with any executables that were previously built, in every directory.

Comment: It's kind of making more sense if I try and make each target separately. As though the `all` target is having problems. Unfortunately I run into something which I do believe is a bit of a make issue: `clang: error: unknown argument: '-floop-optimize'`

Comment: According to Apple, reducing the unknown argument from an error to a warning will do it. Did this, and of course the next thing to happen is that the make threw actual C code compilation errors. I'll take this to the developer and see what he says. Thanks for your help. I knew nothing about make before this, I know quite a bit now.

Comment: Lies! Nobody knows how to use Make, it's impenetrable.